# wcftestclient.exe - Editing the default configuration

Tags: .net, wcf

`WCFTestClient` tool doesn't seem to work if the size of `maxNameTableCharCount` is greater than default value (16384).

Is there any way to modify the settings of the config file generated by this tool, BEFORE the tool generates it?

I can modify the config file contents *after* the service connection is established.  But I am getting an error that is complaining about `maxNameTableCharCount` size while this tool is trying to retrieve the service metadata.

Comment: WCF Test Client is using svcutil.exe underneath so the problem is probably there.

Comment: And regarding the "editing the config file BEFORE..." I think it isn't possible without some advanced hackery (you see for yourself with Reflector).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to increase the same value in the service configuration? AFAIK the `maxNameTableCharCount` should be exposed as a part of the service policy - and should be propagated to the generated client configuration upon generation.

--larsw